# NSTimer - working on iOS 10 but not on iOS 9.3

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, nstimer

I am using `NSTimer` in my iOS app developed in Xamarin. App is working fine on iOS 10 (iPhone 5S) but crashing on my iPad with with iOS 9.3.5.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
timer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(0.3, true, delegate
{
    List<String> keys = this.beaconRegions.Keys.ToList();
    foreach (string identifier in keys)
    {
        this.locationManager.StopRangingBeacons((CLBeaconRegion)this.beaconRegions[identifier]);
        this.locationManager.StopMonitoring(this.beaconRegions[identifier]);
        this.locationManager.StartMonitoring(this.beaconRegions[identifier]);
        this.locationManager.StartRangingBeacons(this.beaconRegions[identifier]);
    }

});
```

And here is the crash log detail:

```
4   CoreFoundation                  0x21c9a234 0x21c72000 + 164404

5   iBeacon                         0x0023564c wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_double_bool_intptr (/<unknown>:1)

6   iBeacon                         0x001e8ecc Foundation_NSTimer_CreateScheduledTimer_double_bool_System_Action_1_Foundation_NSTimer (NSTimer.g.cs:134)

7   iBeacon                         0x001de5b4 iBeacon_LocationManager_turnOnMonitoring (LocationManager.cs:277)

8   iBeacon                         0x001de2ac iBeacon_LocationManager_startMonitoringForBeacons (LocationManager.cs:250)
```

`LocationManager.cs:277` -- this is the code line where I have code for `NStimer`.

Comment: I'm not an xamarin guy, but I wonder if this translates to the block-based `NSTimer` API (see [`scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer)), which was introduced in iOS 10. You have to use the old `target`/`selector` rendition if you're going to support earlier iOS versions.

Comment: @Kyll ok got it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use `System.Threading.Timer` if you are in iOS project.
If you want to use the timer in a PCL project, then you can refer to this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17227/timer-in-portable-class-library

Answer (score 2):

@Rob is right. You should use another methods if you're targeting iOS 9 or below.

This code translates to the newly block-syntax implementation which is not available on iOS versions prior to iOS 10:

> [ObjCRuntime.Introduced(ObjCRuntime.PlatformName.iOS, 10, 0, ObjCRuntime.PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Foundation.NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer/p/System.Double/System.Boolean/System.Action%7BFoundation.NSTimer%7D/

Comment: Ok, so whats alternative method is there which will work on previous iOS version?

Comment: @darshana My 9.3 app has easily coped up with the Nstimer Given in the question Part!